# PHP variables are lost when CakePHP validation fails

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm having a problem with data validation in CakePHP. Whenever data validation fails, the variables that were set in the controller are lost, which messes up the form.

Here is the controller code for add():

```
function add() {
    $joins = array(
        array(
            'table' => 'groups_users',
            'alias' => 'GroupUser',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'User.id = GroupUser.user_id'
            )
        ),
        array(
            'table' => 'groups',
            'alias' => 'Group',
            'type' => 'inner',
            'conditions' => array(
                'GroupUser.group_id = Group.id'
            )
        )
    );

    if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Course->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Course created.');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
        }
    } else {
        $this->set('users', $this->Course->User->find('list', array(
            'fields' => array('User.surname_firstname'),
            'order' => array(
                    'User.surname_firstname'
            ),
            'joins' => $joins,
            'conditions' => array(
                'Group.name' => 'teachers'
            )
        )));
    }
}
```

When the validation fails, the "users" variable that is set towards the end is lost. Anyone ever have this problem before? Is there an easy fix? My project is due in 12 hours and this will look pretty bad.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you only trigger the find() in the else block? Just dont put it there and there are no such issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
if (!empty($this->data)) {
    if ($this->Course->save($this->data)) {
```

into

```
if (!empty($this->data) && $this->Course->save($this->data)) {
```

That way if `$this->data` is not empty it will try to save, and if save succeeds you'll get the success message. If `$this->data` is empty it will not call save, and if `$this->data` contains invalid data then save will fail and the else block will still be executed.